# lost my ASPNETDB.mdf

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express, aspnetdb

I am working on the MVC storefront Rob Conery project and I lost my ASPNET.mdf database !

I would like to have the ASPNET.mdf database in my App_Data folder. I tried to include the db right clicking on it and including it in the project. But on the Server Exporer when I am tring to look at tables there are none.

Here is my Web.Config file :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="CoderForTradersConnectionString"
   connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|CoderForTraders.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include the aspnetdb.mdf from the VisualStudio tool prompt aspnet_regsql and add the database to my project.